# Send a nServiceBus message via SharePoint custom workflow action

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, nservicebus, workflow-activity

I am working on a project to have SharePoint work with another EHR program. In order to do this we want to have a SharePoint custom action send a message to this EHR program via nServiceBus. I feel that it may not be possible due to the setup that needs to happen in order for nServiceBus to send a message. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to expose your EHR endpoint via WCF and have SharePoint send the message to it that way. That way you don't have to take a dependency on NServiceBus in SharePoint and can use its build-in connectivity components to facilitate communication.

Comment: Thank you, we ended up going this route but opening up a server with nServiceBus running on it to WCF. This way the SharePoint workflow can make a call to the web service and in turn it will fire off an nServiceBus event that will send the message to the EHR.